# Centralizing routes into a Service in Angular

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular-routing, single-responsibility-principle

This question focuses on how to manage routing in large-scale apps. I'm still unsure how to handle this, or if tutorials are just far beyond best practices.

Well, let's get to the point. When an application grows, sooner or later there are hundreds of `routerLink` directives with hard-coded strings like

```
<a routerLink="foo">
```

or dynamic ones something like that

```
<a [routerLink]="'/foo/bar/' + myObj.id">
```

That permanent repetition of hard-coded route fragments and dynamic assembly of routes within the directive doesn't really feel right.

In terms of *Don't repeat yourself* and *Single responsibility principle (SRP)* the first thing that comes to my mind is creating something like a *RouteService* that centralizes those routes and can be injected into components. It might also provide constants to the routing modules.

So, although the Angular style guide [preaches to obey SRP](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#single-responsibility-1) this issue is never addressed. And tutorials like the *Tour of Heroes* are typically much too small to take issues into account that occur when writing large-scale applications.

Are there any caveats of using an injectable *Service* to create routes or 
are there any patterns, concepts, frameworks that aim to extract hard-coded routes out of components/templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my SPA in Angular 4 (about 70 subpages) i used `[routerLink]=getRouterLink(page_name)`.
In my components typescript class, i called a link service that read a link to the given page_name from a yaml file in the java backend.
I think this is the most elegant way to apply DRY and SRP to this topic.
It is in fact really a pity, that the angular tutorials don't handle this topic.

Comment: Thanks. Good to hear that I'm not the only one with this issue. Sounds like you had the same idea similar to my RouteService.

Comment: Yes, this is really silly. Maybe you could optimize this by defining a typescript class containing your routes, so you don't have to call a backend each time a view is generated